# How do I make the chapter title in the heading different from the chapter title in the TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr, tocloft

I'm setting a document using the `octavo` class and including the packages `tocloft` and `fancyhdr`. Here are my fancyhdr settings:

```
\fancyhead[CE]{\itshape\booktitle}
\fancyhead[CO]{\itshape\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

I want the chapter numbers to appear in the chapter listing in the TOC, so I'm starting the chapters with e.g.:

```
\chapter[II. Title of Chapter Two]{Title of Chapter Two}
```

This gives me the chapter heading I want ("Title of Chapter Two") and the TOC entry I want ("II. Title of Chapter Two"), but the header on every right page is the latter, when I want it to be the former.

Is there a way I can do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional argument of `\chapter` is used for the ToC and `\markboth`. If you want a chapter title without a number, but a different thing in ToC, and another in the headers, you can use `\addcontentsline` for the ToC, `\chapter*` for the not numbered title and set `\markboth` to have even more title versions at the left and/or right header (even without `fancyhdr`). This can be simplified with a macro, but I set it manually in two chaptersto make more clear the approach.

Note that no one of these chapter title versions should have the number that will be wrong if you add\remove\move any other chapter. If only should be numbered in ToC, just allow a numbered ToC setting the `secnumdepth` counter, since `\chapter*`  will be not cumbered anyway.

In the example, the four chapter name versions in the MWE are just repeated characters, AAAA, EEE, etc. instead of titles for humans beings (ugly, but easier to check where is ending each in the PDF):

```
\documentclass{octavo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\chapter*{AAAA\markboth{EEEE}{OOOO}} % Title ≠ even header ≠  odd header ≠ ToC 
\stepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter} SSSSS}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter*{ZZZZ\markboth{XXXX}{CCCC}} % Title ≠ even header ≠  odd header ≠ ToC 
\stepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter} UUUUU}
\lipsum[1-10]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so very, very much! I really appreciate the help—this does everything I wanted it to and more!